# How do i add items from a dropdown list then get the text of each item

Tags: java, css, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have a dropdown of 10 items. How can I write a code that would store all these items in some sort of list so that i can compare each of the items to each other? The layout of the page is:

```
<select id="blahBlah">

 <option value = "0" selected="selected">fghgjjyg1</option>
 <option value = "1">dghdfgffg2</option>
 <option value = "2">fsd gdf3</option>
 <option value = "3">f fdgfdg4</option>
 <option value = "4">dfsgf5</option>
 <option value = "5">fdgfdsgsd6</option>
 <option value = "6">sgfgsfgdf7</option>
 <option value = "7">fdsgsdgg8</option>
 <option value = "8">fdsgfds9</option>
 <option value = "9">dfsdfs10</option>
</select>
```

So there are numbers and the end of each item - I want to be able to verify that the numbers on the top are smaller than the numbers below it.

Comment: Why not put the values into an array?

Comment: I think people are missing the `Selenium` tag here. What **Selenium** code have you got right now?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Webdrivers findElements function

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//select[@id=blahBlah]/option));
for(WebElement e : options){
    System.out.println(e.getText())
}
```

That's generally what you want to do. Your HTML looks a little odd so I'm not sure if the xpaths are correct or not but this should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Without using jQuery:

```
var selectDom  = document.getElementById("blahBlah");
var optionsDom = selectDom.getElementsByTagName("option");
var optionsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(optionsDom);
var theArrayThatYouWant = optionsArray.map(function(option) { return option.text });
```

Comment: You are missing what tags are applied to the question, in particular `Selenium`. jQuery is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery:

```
var yourArray = []
$('#blahBlah option').each(function(){yourArray.push($(this).text())});
```

Comment: I was actually hoping to do it using Java. I should've prefaced by saying im new to programming :(

Comment: You are missing what tags are applied to the question, in particular `Selenium`. jQuery is totally unnecessary.